# next.js Firebase Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I have deployed a vercel hosted next app with firebase authentication that works for users. But mysteriously during the "npm run build" phase this error pops up:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment).

and

> code: 'auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment',
> customData: {}

```
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  const auth = getAuth()

  const handleLogin = () => {
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('with redirect: ' + result)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then((result) => {
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
      const token = credential.accessToken

      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user
      console.log(user)

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      console.log(error)
      // ...
    })
```

This is the meat of the authentication code. I stuck as closely as I could to the firebase docs.

Is there a reason related to next.js or the "Authorized Domains" firebase requires that this build/deployment error is being caused?

Thank you for your consideration.

**Bonus Info**
Versions:

Firebase: 9.8.4
Next Js: 12.1.5

This is how I'm initializing the firebase app.

```
const initMyFirebase = () => {
  if (!getApps().length) {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

    // creating auth for authentication
    const auth = getAuth(app)
```

```
const theme = extendTheme({ colors })

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  initMyFirebase()
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      {/*// <ChakraProvider>*/}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the issue, nor remember how exactly to do this, but ensure that Firebase is using the JS mode and not NodeJS mode, or the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this for myself by initializing getAuth(app) just the once instead of multiple times and then exporting it to the places I needed it. I also stopped carrying user auth state in a hook and instead wrapped my entire application in an AuthContext.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Head>
          <title>...........</title>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="................"
          />
          {/*<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>*/}
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  )
}
```

**AuthContextProvider:**

```
    import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth'
import firebaseApp from './firebase'

const initialUser: any = null

const AuthContext = createContext({
  authUser: initialUser,
  loading: true,
})

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<User | null>(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)

  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unSub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setAuthUser(user)
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unSub
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authUser, loading }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContext
```

Comment: I am having same issue. Can you share the code snippet, please?

Comment: Hi Lee Ming, I can send it on if you're still having this issue?